# Show Firebase Auth error message on Flutter TextFormField

Tags: flutter

I use FirebaseAuth on my flutter app.

So, in my register Screen I use `Form` -> and several `TextFormField`.

For example, this is my form:

```
Form(
              key: formKey,
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  const FormTitle(text: "Nombre"),
                  TextForm(
                    hintText: "Ingresá tu nombre",
                    fieldContent: "nombre",
                    fieldName: "name",
                    formValues: formValues,
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 24),
                  const FormTitle(text: "Apellido"),
                  TextForm(
                    hintText: "Ingresá tu apellido",
                    fieldContent: "apellido",
                    fieldName: "lastName",
                    formValues: formValues,
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 24),
                  const FormTitle(text: "E-mail"),
                  EmailForm(
                    hintText: "Ingresá tu e-mail",
                    fieldName: "email",
                    formValues: formValues,
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 24),
                  const FormTitle(text: "Número de teléfono"),
                  PhoneForm(
                    fieldName: "phone",
                    formValues: formValues,
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 24),
                  const FormTitle(text: "Contraseña"),
                  PasswordForm(
                    hintText: "Creá una contraseña",
                    fieldName: "password",
                    formValues: formValues,
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 24),
                  const FormTitle(text: "Repetir contraseña"),
                  PasswordForm(
                    hintText: "Repetí la contraseña",
                    formValues: formValues,
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 24),
                ],
              ),
            ),ç
```

and this is my TextForm:

```
TextFormField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    hintText: hintText,
  ),
  validator: (value) {
    if (value != null) {
      if (value.isEmpty) {
        return 'Ingrese un $fieldContent';
      }
      if (value.length < 2) {
        return 'Ingrese un $fieldContent válido';
      }
    }
  },
  onChanged: (value) {
    formValues[fieldName] = value;
    print(formValues);
  },
  autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
);
```

What I'm trying to achieve is *in case of error* on the `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()`, set the `TextFormField` in error and show a message.

So, how can I set the error message of my `TextFormField` based on the method response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a variable above `build()` Function :

```
  class _ScreenState extends State<Screen> {
    String? error;

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return YourWidget();
    }
  }
```

2. Modify your submit button, and add this `try-catch` code :

```dart
  try {
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
      email: email,
      password: password,
    );
  } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
    if (e.code == 'weak-password') {
      error = 'The password provided is too weak.';
    } else if (e.code == 'email-already-in-use') {
      error = 'The account already exists for that email.';
    } else {
      error = e.message;
    }
    setState(() {});
  }
```

3. And to display error in text field, You can use `errorText` property of `InputDecoration` :

```
TextFormField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    hintText: hintText,
    errorText: error
  ),
  validator: (value) {
    if (value != null) {
      if (value.isEmpty) {
        return 'Ingrese un $fieldContent';
      }
      if (value.length < 2) {
        return 'Ingrese un $fieldContent válido';
      }
    }
  },
  onChanged: (value) {
    formValues[fieldName] = value;
    print(formValues);
  },
  autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
);
```